# netflix on kodi/openELEC

Tags: streaming-video, media

I want to use my rpi3b as a htpc. So far my best option is kodi, I think. The main reason I got it is so my father could watch mlb.tv, so it is prority #1. I would like to stream Netflix on there aswell, for example when some friends are over.

For kodi I already have an mlb.tv addon, but for netflix I still don't really know what to do. there is NetfliXBMC, but it seems like it is a lot of trouble since it doesn't run on kodi standalones like openELEC out of the box. Also, for Netflix I can use a windows pc in the same network, for example to stream it to the rpi.

Are there any alternatives to kodi that support mlbtv and netflix? I am willing to run a completely different operating system on the rpi.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you look into something like [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/web-browser-released/) as it includes HTML5 hardware decoding and as Netflix now includes HTML 5 support it should be more effective than xbmc add ons. But as I have not personally tested it I can not vouch for its effectiveness.

Comment: @lenny I just realized that this is likely to not work as Netflix uses encryption that the Pi probably doesn't support, but I don't know it's been a long time since I last checked for support